# Trouble swapping datestamps in a log file's name using Bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

I'm trying to swap the date in a log file's name using a bash script. I cannot seem to get the date's to play nice however.

When I try to swap the dates using `sed`, the original date is still in the filename (I'm echoing instead of using `mv` for now):

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
YESTERDATE= date -d 'yesterday 13:00' '+%Y-%m-%d'
echo "$DATE"
echo "$YESTERDATE"
for LOGFILE in *.$DATE;
do
    newfile="$(echo ${LOGFILE} |sed -e 's/$DATE/$YESTERDATE/')" ;
    echo "$newfile"
    #mv -- "$LOGFILE" "$newfile";
done
```

The log files I want changed are only the ones with todays date in them. The format is `log_file.log.2018-07-17`. I want it to be changed to `log_file.log.2018-07-16`.

Is the issue with how I am using variable names in the `sed` command?

Comment: quick suggestion, try: `sed -e "s/$DATE/$YESTERDATE/"`

Comment: I think Sundeep is correct, the single quotes are preventing the variable expansion for DATE and YESTERDATE.  Change that line as Sundeep has suggested: newfile="$(echo ${LOGFILE} |sed -e "s/$DATE/$YESTERDATE/")"  with $() the nested quotes will be fine.

Comment: Replace `YESTERDATE= date -d 'yesterday 13:00' '+%Y-%m-%d'` with `YESTERDATE="$(date -d 'yesterday 13:00' '+%Y-%m-%d')"`

Comment: See http://rextester.com/LHNH4768. Inian is right, the `$YESTERDATE` variable is empty when inside `for` loop if you do not place its definition inside `"$()"`.

Comment: The tool `sed` is dated. A lot of features are missing in this tool. Why not use a modern scripting language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with quoting. This line

```
newfile="$(echo ${LOGFILE} |sed -e 's/$DATE/$YESTERDATE/')"
```

uses single quotes for the sed - and single quotes prevent the variables being substituted. You'll see the problem if you try something simple like

```
echo "$(echo '$foo')"
```

Instead, try

```
newfile=$(echo ${LOGFILE} |sed -e "s/$DATE/$YESTERDATE/")
```

Comment: That is indeed correct! I guess I need to brush up on my Bash syntax. Thank you!

Comment: In addition, you need to use double quotes around `$LOGFILE` everywhere. The curly braces are not necessary or useful.

Answer (score 0):

One thing it's `""`, second it's bad  `YESTERDATE` try to echo it. For me working something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
#change No.1
YESTERDATE=$(date -d 'yesterday 13:00' '+%Y-%m-%d')
echo "$DATE"
echo "$YESTERDATE"
for LOGFILE in *.$DATE;
do
    #change No.2
    newfile="$(echo ${LOGFILE} |sed -e "s/$DATE/$YESTERDATE/")" ;
    echo "$newfile"
    #mv -- "$LOGFILE" "$newfile";
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi modify below line in your script like :-

```
 newfile=$(echo ${LOGFILE} | sed -e 's/'$DATE'/'$YESTERDATE'/')
```

in `sed`, string variable should be under single quote '